# How to make a menu contribution item stays first before the additional Actions I added to the same menu?

Tags: eclipse, contextmenu, rcp

I have an Eclipse RCP based Application, in which I have a menu of one item added through extensions, which is called *kill*. 
I am using this item to be shown upon right click of a tree viewer items. Now, for the various tree items, I add different `Actions` for different tree items (to be shown in right click of each item).

For `TreeItem1` I added additional actions such as *do* and *Dont*. For `TreeItem2` I added additional Action that is *love*.

On the right click of items, custom menus are shown (as needed) but the *kill* is shown at the end of the menu that pops up on the right click. Can anyone have an idea and help me please to make at at the beginning?

current behavior:
`TreeItem1`->rightclick-> *do*, *dont*, *kill*.
`TreeItem2`->rightclick-> *love*, *kill*
`TreeItem3`->rightclick-> *kill*.

Desired behavior:
`TreeItem1`->rightclick-> *kill*, *do*, *dont*.
`TreeItem2`->rightclick-> *kill*, *love*.
`TreeItem3`->rightclick-> *kill*.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add named separators to the menu using extensions and use the names (or IDs, depending on the extension point) of those separators in menu bar path (or location URI) of the action contribution and when adding actions to menu programmatically.